# How do I get to scroll smoothly through a customized list view?

Tags: android, listview

My custom List View just won't scroll smoothly enough and all the solutions that I looked up on this site were beyond my understanding.People who are more than willing to explain from previous questions are equally welcome as those providing the solution.Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String []titles = {"CAPTAIN AMERICA", "DOCTOR STRANGE", "THOR", "SPIDERMAN"};
String []desciption = {"CHRIS EVANS", "BENEDICT CUMBERBATCH", "CHRIS HEMSWORTH", "TOM HOLLAND"};
int []image = {R.drawable.capamerica, R.drawable.doctorstrange, R.drawable.thor, R.drawable.spidey};
ListView lv;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    MyAdapter adap = new MyAdapter(this, titles, desciption, image);
    lv.setAdapter(adap);
}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
String []title;
String []desc;
Context context;
int []img;;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] titles, String[] desciption, int[] image)
{
    context = mainActivity;
    title = titles;
    desc = desciption;
    img = image;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return title.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

public class Info {
    ImageView iv;
    TextView tv;
    TextView tv1;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Info info = new Info();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
    info.iv = v.findViewById(R.id.imgview);
    info.tv = v.findViewById(R.id.titlestring);
    info.tv1 = v.findViewById(R.id.descriptionstring);
    info.iv.setImageResource(img[i]);
    info.tv.setText(title[i]);
    info.tv1.setText(desc[i]);
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: use RecyclerView, the BindView method will get things cached and things will run more smoothly..

Comment: Or add a ViewHolder class in your existing code

Comment: and what are the sizes of the images you are using?

Comment: But if I were to do it this way how could I??

Comment: no what I mean to say was image's size ? i.e in kb's or mb's

Comment: @AbdulKawee I got about two images over 250kb's.

Comment: The ImageView dimension can be 150x150, but if the Bitmap inserted on it is 600x600 it will run slowly. You need to downsample the bitmaps while loading if thats the case

Comment: You got some heavy pics , you have to do many things , like make different dimens for different screen and reduce size of screen

Comment: @AbdulKawee I mean no offence but could you be a little more specific??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using ViewHolder design pattern:**
Your code is calling findViewById() frequently during the scrolling of ListView, which can slow down performance. Even when the Adapter returns an inflated view for recycling, you still need to look up the elements and update them. A way around repeated use of findViewById() is to use the "view holder" design pattern.

This is clearly mentioned under [Google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

Example:

```
static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;
        private TextView description;
        private ImageView image;
    }

ViewHolder holder;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

if (view == null) {
    view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titlestring);
    holder.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionstring);
    holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgview);
    view.setTag(holder);

}else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}

holder.title.setText(titles[position]);
holder.description.setText(description[position]);
holder.image.setImageResource(image[position])
return view;
}
```

**Lazyloading of images:**
Actually, when you scroll list view, each time a row is visible, then getView function will get triggered. So, if a user scroll a large list view fast up and down, then getView will be triggered many times and scrolling will not be smooth. So it is advised to carry out image loading in a separate thread for smooth scrolling of list view.

Also make sure, you are not creating threads more than a limit. Recommended limit is 6-7 based on maximum number of list items visible to the user.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What's this Modal Class supposed to be???Could you please make these changes with respect to my code

Comment: Updated the code. Please check if this helps you. If you are using images in list view, on top of viewholder design pattern, it is recommended to use lazyloading of images. This is mentioned under same link above

Comment: What's lazyloading supposed to mean??Your code worked but without the images.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.